# How to view cache record in Laravel 7?

Tags: caching, laravel-7

I have bunch of codes from old team using Laravel7. I have 2 endpoint:

- wd/request-otp (working, OTP received at my test email)
- wdreq (always said "Your OTP not valid!")

So, I checked the relevant codes:

**resource/views/emails/otp.blade.php**

```
<p>Your OTP:<p>
<p><h1>{{$otp}}</h1></p>
```

**WithdrawService.php**

```
    /**
     * @param $requestOTP
     * @param $otpConfirmation
     * @throws CustomException
     */
    public function isValidOTP($requestOTP, $otpConfirmation)
    {
        if ($requestOTP !== (int) $otpConfirmation) {
            throw new CustomException('Your OTP not valid', [$requestOTP, $otpConfirmation]);
        }
    }
```

**OTP.php**

```
    /**
     * Create OTP number and store in the cache
     *
     * @param string $prefix
     * @param mixed $phone
     * @return integer
     */
    public function cacheTheOTP($prefix, $phone)
    {
        $OTP = rand(100000, 999999);
        Cache::put([$this->OTPKey($prefix, $phone) => $OTP], \Carbon\Carbon::now()->addMinutes(10));
        return $OTP;
    }
```

Maybe $requestOTP is always != $otpConfirmation (received at my email, so I can see it). So, I need to check, what value in $requestOTP, was it the same with OTP sent to my email? Are there any ways to check cache records? What should I do to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

```
Cache::put('key', 'value', $seconds);
Cache::rememberForever('users', function () {
    return DB::table('users')->get();
}); 
Cache::get('key');
Cache::has('key');
Cache::pull('key');
```

Comment: this answer was flagged for low quality, please better the answer with more supporting info and an explanation